# Send gmail using java with service account setup for OAuth

Tags: java, email, oauth, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I have setup service account following : https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount link.

Then trying to send gmail using below code :

```
public static String getAccessToken(String email) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
 {
    GoogleCredential credential1 = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("Project-abcd.json")) .createScoped(Collections.singleton(GMAIL_SCOPE));
    System.out.println("refreshToken : "+credential1.refreshToken());
    return credential1.getAccessToken();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String email = "from_email";
    ServiceAccountGmail sag=new ServiceAccountGmail();
    String authToken = sag.getAccessToken(email);
    System.out.println("OAuth TOken is : "+authToken);
    OAuth2Authenticator.initialize();
   SMTPTransport smtpTransport = OAuth2Authenticator.connectToSmtp("smtp.gmail.com", 587, email, authToken, true);
   System.out.println("Successfully authenticated to SMTP.\n");
}
```

But getting below error :

> Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect
>       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:403)
>       at org.serviceaccount.oauth.OAuth2Authenticator.connectToSmtp(OAuth2Authenticator.java:127)
>       at org.serviceaccount.oauth.ServiceAccountGmail.main(ServiceAccountGmail.java:52)

I am able to get the auth token but when I pass this to `connectToSmtp()` method facing unable to connect issue.

Comment: Try to [change account access for less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) and apply [Less secure apps](http://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps). Check [how to impersonate a user with service account](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account) to access GMAIL API. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here i am trying to avoid changing the account for less secure apps settings. So i did set up Service account to implement Google's OAuth2 mechanism. This way the application will be treated as secured app and hence google will allow to send and receive emails without changing the less secure apps settings.